# (Python/Tweepy) - Can I query for the twitter profile that contains a specific URL?

Tags: python, api, url, twitter, tweepy

[image: example picture]

Where it says google.com...

I am trying to create a script that takes the url "google.com" and then returns the profile page or information.

What I have so far does exactly what I want it to, except you must give it the screen name and then it uses the screen name to fetch the profile.

```
import tweepy
from pprint import pprint


consumer_key = 'something'
consumer_secret = 'something'
access_token = 'something'
access_token_secret = 'something'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth)


user =api.get_user('google')

print user
```

If Tweepy does not offer support for this, I am open to all suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. you are using the wrong end point for the job, you should use [this](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/users/search) 
   end point which in tweepy corresponds to api.search_users(q)
2. check [here](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search) on how to construct the parameter q
3. If it works if you pass the url as parameter depends on the contents of particular twitter user's home page and other factors. Probably you will have a better chance if you disassemble the url and use the domain name ie: api.search_users("Google com")

Comment: Thanks, that query worked. What is the format of the result? JSON?

Comment: Twitter API end point returns json, sometime drivers cast it to something else

Answer (score 1):

# Class User contains all the profile features of the user
 # Here userid is the screen name of the user

```
 class User(object): 

      def __init__(self, userid):
          self.userid = userid
          self.user = api.get_user(self.userid)
```

# Get the profile description of the user

```
      def get_profile(self):
          return self.user.description
```